# Delaying route change in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, page-transition

Is there a way to delay a route change in Gatsby? I would use it to fade out a page before fading in the new page. I am doing this using the gatsby-browser api. Fading in the new page works well, but fading out the old one doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what have you tried at all and how did you have achieved the fade-in effect. I would suggest another approach which is what I've always used to create page transitions (both fade-in, fade-out, and others): using [gatsby-plugin-transition-link](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-page-transitions-with-plugin-transition-link/).

It allows you to create your custom animation or use some default or predefined, you can check its demo site [here](https://gatsby-plugin-transition-link.netlify.com/) where there's an example of a few transitions.

For predefined transitions (the easiest way) you only need to import de component and use it like this:

```
import AniLink from "gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink"

<AniLink paintDrip to="page-2">
  Go to Page 2
</AniLink>
```

For custom transitions, you need to define de `entry` and exit `effect`, such as:

```
<TransitionLink
  exit={{
    length: length,
    trigger: ({ exit, node }) =>
      this.someCustomDefinedAnimation({ exit, node, direction: "out" }),
  }}
  entry={{
    length: 0,
    trigger: ({ exit, node }) =>
      this.someCustomDefinedAnimation({ exit, node, direction: "in" }),
  }}
  {...props}
>
  {props.children}
</TransitionLink>
```

For further information check out their [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-page-transitions-with-plugin-transition-link/#custom-transitions).

Moreover, there are a bunch of plugins for [gatsby-page-transitions](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-page-transitions/?=page-tran) but they usually have a dirtiest and more complex integration, with also less feedback (in terms of global downloads).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ferran. I have used gatsby-plugin-transition-link before but that seems like a lot of effort for a simple page transition. So I set out to build a simple transition without a plugin. The result can be seen here:  https://github.com/wernerglinka/gatsby-starter-square1/blob/master/gatsby-browser.js    This could be improved if I could delay the route change so the fade out is executed properly.